# Schema Compare - How to take referenced projects into account?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, schema-compare

I've created a database project and several databases projects that reference that project. I would like to use *VS2008 Schema Compare* to compare the schema of one of the databases to my development database.

So far, so good. But when I check the result, it says it will **skip all references**!?

[image: Screen shot schema compare]

Question: How can I include the referenced database into my compare?

*Ps. Comparing the "base" database first and then the other database won't work either, because it will result in drops.*

Comment: Might be offtopic, but try this: http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/

Comment: I have an idea.

Why don't you export database into .ERD file, then use ERD modeler tool (like ERWin) to compare them? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each project must be compared individually. More info about [pros and cons here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dukek/archive/2009/12/31/the-pros-and-cons-of-partial-projects-and-database-project-references.aspx). Hopefully it will be better in the future...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250.aspx) on "Compare and Synchronize Database Schemas" the meaning of `Skip Referenced` is

`The object exists in a referenced database and does not need to be dropped or created`

That basically means that those objects already exist in the database and won't be created or deleted, they're unchanged.

Comment: This is not true. In my example there is a referenced stored procedure missing and this procedure needs to be created. Yet... this procedure isn't even mentioned. But what I want to do is compare both databases.

Comment: Can you remove the answer? It being no answer at all?

Comment: For better understanding please send screenshots the structure of your databases. Which stored procedure is it?